# why is SQL CASE returning both true and false?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hitting a baffling issue in SQL. Somehow, a JOIN in a CASE statement is returning both TRUE and FALSE!

If you run the below (I'm using SQL Server 2008), you'll see the effect. The JOIN creates 2 records, based on the CASE statements.

Any ideas how to stop this?

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(id int PRIMARY KEY, fieldA nvarchar(MAX))
    INSERT INTO #table1
    SELECT 1, 'ABC Airlines'


    CREATE TABLE #table2(field_id int PRIMARY KEY, fieldB nvarchar(MAX))
    INSERT INTO #table2
    SELECT 1, 'ABC Airlines'
    UNION
    SELECT 2, '*** OTHER ***'

    SELECT  * 
    FROM    #table1 t
    JOIN    #table2 t2 ON t2.fieldB =  CASE WHEN t.fieldA <> t2.fieldB THEN '*** OTHER ***' ELSE t.fieldA END
```

Comment: Makes sense to me, what behavior were you trying for?

Comment: It should only return the 1 line from #table1, joined onto field_id 1 in #table2; when I run it it returns 2 lines:

Comment: `CASE` statement is fetching *all* matching records from `#table2` **plus** any records with `fieldB = *** OTHER ***`. Did you expect sth else?

Comment: Yeah - t.fieldA <> t2.fieldB. So why is it joining on #table2.fieldB = '*** Other ***'?

Comment: Because when `t.fieldA <> t2.fieldB` join condition boils down to 't2.fieldB = *** OTHER'. Thus the second record is also being fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using #table2.fieldB as a JOIN condition, so you are getting 2 values ('ABC Airlines' and 'Other'). Your expected result can be achieved if you change your query this way

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    #table1 t
JOIN    #table2 t2 ON t.fieldA = CASE WHEN t.fieldA <> t2.fieldB THEN '*** OTHER ***' ELSE t2.fieldB END
```

Answer (score 0):

When you will insert data into #table1 & #table2 then your tables will look like below

## table1

id  fieldA

1   ABC Airlines

## table2

id  fieldB

1   ABC Airlines

2   *** OTHER ***

Now when you are joining both table your where condition says that if fieldA not equal to fieldB then '*** OTHER** ' otherwise fieldA, so as a result when ABC Airlines<> **OTHER**  then you are passing  **OTHER *** as a substitute while joining. So for both rows data will match and you will get both result. Please change case condition based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

why wouldn't you want:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    #table1 t
JOIN    #table2 t2 ON t.fieldA =  t2.fieldB
```

It is a bad practice to use case statements and inequalities in joins. Based on your end result desired all you want is an ordinary inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
SELECT  * 
FROM #table1 t JOIN
     #table2 t2
     ON t2.fieldB = t.fieldA OR t2.fieldB = '*** OTHER ***' ;
```

The only time this is not equivalent to your logic is when `fieldA` is `NULL`, but that doesn't seem to be an issue with your data.

My guess is, however, is that you want the '*** OTHER ***' value when there is *no match at all*.  That is no what your logic would do.  If that is the case, then `apply` solves the problem:

```
select *
from #table1 t apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from #table2 t2
      where t2.fieldB = t.fieldA or t2.fieldB = '*** OTHER ***'
      order by (case when t2.fieldB = t.fieldA then 1 else 2 end)
     ) t2;
```